# I am new to CakePHP. Is this site menu sensible and conventional?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I need a bit of feedback to make sure I'm not completely missing the point of CakePHP/MVC.

I'm designing a mini-cms in CakePHP--essentially a photo album. I'm looking to have a standard, boiler-plate drop down menu on every page. Naturally, the menu needs to be dynamic as the user deletes and adds albums.

My goal: Build something that moves in the opposite direction of `View::actionRequest()` (ie, instead of view calling back to the controller, have the controller push a set variable to the View class before it renders.) My understanding is that `View::requestAction()` is not very graceful and is quite slow.

This is my model for the table containing the menu keywords. `app/Model/ModelItem.php`

```
class MenuItem extends AppModel {
    public function buildMainMenu() {
        return $this->find('all');
    }
}
```

Since I want it everywhere, I put the call in the `AppController`

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->loadModel('MenuItem');
        $this->set('mainMenuItems',$this->MenuItem->buildMainMenu());
    }
}
```

And this is an element that gets dumped into the top of my default layout for the CSS
 - Element File: `app/View/Element/navigation.ctp`
 - Layout: `app/View/Element/Layout/default.ctp`

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <?php
    foreach($mainMenuItems as $item) {
        echo "<li>".$item['MenuItem']['name']."</li>";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

I end up with a lovely, bullet list of all the items in the table. Am I completely mucking this up? Do I have it all wrong? I have no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your approach. Here are a few notes though, completely optional:

- I'd move the menu fetching code from `beforeFilter()` to [`beforeRender()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3abeforeRender). There no reason to do it that early, you may throw an exception before the menu is needed, or you may redirect your user to another page. Additionally, you have more information about the request there, so you can do things like highlight the current page/item/user in the menu.
- Move the element rendering code into some sort of a MenuHelper, which will make your layour cleaner (e.g. `$this->Menu->render()` in the layout). You could also use the HtmlHelper to render your items through cake, and let cake take care of markup correctness.
- If you move the rendering into a helper, implement some sort of caching scheme for the whole thing, to speed things up - if it's necessary. Whether the caching is possible or not, or whether you should do it in your controller or your helper is entirely up to you and your app :)

I guess the overall advice is to try to isolate bits of functionality from the rest of the app; it's easier to read, maintain and modify.

Comment: +1 for the beforeRender() move (passing stuff to the view should never be done in beforeFilter)

Answer (score 0):

I'd parcel it up into an element and use request action to fetch the data when you output the menu in the layout/view:

/app/View/Elements/main_menu.ctp:

```
$mainMenuItems = $this->requestAction('/menu_items/buildMainMenu');

<ul id="navigation">
    <?php
    foreach($mainMenuItems as $item) {
        echo "<li>".$item['MenuItem']['name']."</li>";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

and include it in your layout/view with:

```
echo $this->Element('main_menu');
```

This way, if you have a view/layout (e.g. Ajax) that doesn't need the menu you wont waste a database query.